# Extract part of a string in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, substring

I have a question how to extract a substring.

Here an example string:

`{{from,005021889988,,Amt},{setup-from,66,,},{alert-to,66,ConTeach Zentrale,ConTeach Zentrale},{conn-to,66,ConTeach Zentrale,ConTeach Zentrale},{transfer-to,10,kb,Kai Büsing},{conn-to,66,ConTeach Zentrale,ConTeach Zentrale {disc-to,,,},{rel-from,66,ConTeach Zentrale,ConTeach Zentrale}}`

The goal is to extract *'66,ConTeach Zentrale,ConTeach Zentrale'* between *'{conn-to,'* and *'},'*

Any ideas?

Comment: what query(s) have you tried so far? I see 2x '{conn-to' snippets in your example string so how do you determine which one to extract?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) with a regular expression. But you need to define your requirements exactly. Like [markp commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222733/extract-part-of-a-string-in-postgres#comment437239_222733), there is ambiguity with multiple matches.

```
SELECT substring($string FROM '{conn-to,(.*?)},')
```

The part between parentheses is returned. This returns the *first* match, and the [non-greedy quantifier `*?`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-QUANTIFIERS-TABLE) prefers the *shortest* match.